# как обойти рекурсией дерево и возвращать значение, без удаления вложенных элементов в дереве?

Tags: javascript

Дерево возвращает правильный срез, если только сразу ввести целиком искомое значение. Если же в инпуте искать любое значение, то все вложенные значения удаляются `splice` и дальше уже не найти дочерние обьекты. Есть ли решение без удаления в цикле найти искомое значение?

```
const tree = [
    {
        "uuid": "68966289-4628-47a5-a650-221568f55637",
        "name": "test_1",
        "users": [
            {
                "uuid": "377d4e28-dd06-411c-9680-ad61101b0ad3",
                "name": "123",
                "username": "user_1"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "uuid": "99033184-20e3-44a2-9a09-596832328645",
        "name": "Группа 1",
        "users": [
            {
                "uuid": "5647db0b-ae48-4ed0-b78b-4637a789abcb",
                "name": "useruser",
                "username": "user3010"
            },
            {
                "uuid": "2f451ed6-e6e0-401d-9779-2f199f126c32",
                "name": "Семенов Иван Семенович",
                "username": "future_man"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "uuid": "f57cba61-9006-473c-822c-9bb612476bb7",
        "name": "Подразделение 3003",
        "users": [
            {
                "uuid": "a7fbdee5-afd0-4fec-8f14-c6b881d54b53",
                "name": "Балунов Егор Георгиевич",
                "username": "balun"
            },
            {
                "uuid": "a35d2acb-358a-48a6-8186-491cf3bfaa88",
                "name": "Каблуков Дмитрий Дмитриевич",
                "username": "kablukov_dd"
            },
            {
                "uuid": "6c6ac937-86f3-4c4a-8238-4be28344cd6b",
                "name": "Лобанов Игорь Анатольевич",
                "username": "lobanov_ia"
            },

        ]
    },
    {
        "uuid": "8e62ec22-2be0-4de8-9e74-33fdcc65eba4",
        "name": "Подразделение 3004",
        "users": [
            {
                "uuid": "64a3f291-256d-4092-b540-3f3cbbfe3dd1",
                "name": "Акулина Святославовна Лукина",
                "username": "mili_04"
            },
        ]
    },
]

function filter(data, inputValue) {
    return data.filter((element) => checkState(element, inputValue));
}

function checkState(element, inputValue) {
    const filterValues = inputValue.trim();
    let states = false;
    states = getState(element, filterValues);
    return states
}

function getState(data, inputValue, state = false) {
    let i = -1;
    for (const value of Object.values(data)) {
        i+=1;
        if (typeof value === 'object' && value !== null && Object.keys(value).length > 0) {
            let stateElem = getState(value, inputValue);
            if (stateElem === false){
                if (Array.isArray(data)) {
                    data.splice(i,1)
                    i--
                }

            } else {
                state = true
            }

        } else {
            if (state === false) {
                state = JSON.stringify(value).toLowerCase().includes(inputValue.toLowerCase());
            } else {
                return state;
            }
        }
    }
    return state;
}
console.log(filter(tree, "Балунов Егор Георгиевич"));

filter(this.treeGroupsUsers, "Балунов Егор Георгиевич")
```

Answer (score 1):

Все можно сделать значительно проще...

```
const flat = (arr, fieldName = 'users') => arr.reduce((acm, val) => Array.isArray(val[fieldName]) ? acm.concat(val, flat(val[fieldName])) : acm.concat(val), []);
const find = (name = 'Балунов Егор Георгиевич') => flat(tree).find((item) => item.name === name);
find() // {uuid: "a7fbdee5-afd0-4fec-8f14-c6b881d54b53", name: "Балунов Егор Георгиевич", username: "balun"}
```